# FileUpload.FileBytes not storing all the image data

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I have the following code to upload the image:

```
FileUpload uniformItemImageFileUpload = uniformItemsGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("UniformImageInsert") as FileUpload;
byte[] itemBytes = uniformItemImageFileUpload.FileBytes;
```

And the following to bind to the database:

```
OracleParameter itemImageParameter = new OracleParameter("itemImage", OracleDbType.Blob, 4000);
itemImageParameter.Value = itemImageBytes;
oraCommand.Parameters.Add(itemImageParameter);
```

I have a problem, that when the image is uploaded through this mechanism, it does not store all the binary data of that image, but it only stores part of it if it is an image greater then 4kb. However, the problem is not the storage, since the 4000 size of the blob can fit larger files, in fact if I upload it directly through the SQL Navigator it can store it fully, with no problems, however, when trying to upload the same image through the code, it does not store all of it.

Has any one encountered this problem? how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the Blob to the OracleParameter, i.e.

```
OracleParameter itemImageParameter = new OracleParameter("itemImage", OracleDbType.Blob, itemBytes.Length);
itemImageParameter.Value = itemImageBytes;
oraCommand.Parameters.Add(itemImageParameter);
```

Hopefully that will work :)